# What clipboard formats does SAP read?

Tags: excel, vba, abap

We have an automated process that interfaces with the SAP GUI via Excel, copying table data from an Excel spreadsheet into the Windows clipboard and then pasting it out to an SAP "multiselect" modal window. I would like to bypass the use of Excel by directly sending data to the clipboard in the appropriate format, but it isn't clear what formats SAP can read, and my Google searches all just turn up information on how to press the clipboard-related buttons.

I have already written code to access the GUI directly and write the values to the multiselect table, but this way is *much* slower than using the clipboard. Any information on how to speed this process up would be greatly appreciated, whether it pertains to the appropriate clipboard format or some other way to rapidly transfer the data.

Comment: Is there a reason *why* you want to interface to SAP using the GUI? Can you not go the route of using a BAPI or web service? Using the GUI is definitely not a recommended route, unless you absolutely have to... (for example, if you're simulating user interaction with the system).

Comment: I was told when I came on board that the group was waiting for back end access of some sort, and in the meantime had automated the process via the GUI. I _despise_ automating GUIs, and would love to use another alternative, but the existing automated process is rather involved and is unfortunately already built around the GUI. If you have information on the BAPI or web service, neither of which I have heard of previously, I would greatly appreciate it, but I also need an answer to the original question if you have one.

Comment: The BAPI or web service to be used would depend on the data you're interface to the SAP system. In a SAP ECC system you can use transaction `BAPI` to find a list of BAPIs you can use. Services used to be nicely documented in the Enterprise Services Workplace but that seems to have been retired and I can't seem to find an adequate replacement. Regarding your original question, what are you using to automate the GUI? And which version of SAP GUI are you using?

Comment: Using Python + COM to automate the 7.4 GUI. I think I've got the clipboard issue figured out. I will definitely check out the BAPI transaction. Thanks!